# Upgrade Cpu on intel 82865g motherboard

Tags: cpu, motherboard, chipset

i would like to try to improve my pc performanc but i'm not sure about cpu compatibility.

My Motherboard is (i suppose )  aOpen ez 65 with intel i82865g chipset. My cpu is a P4 2.8 ghz  without hyperthreading so,i think, northwood core.

I would like to improve it with a p4 3.4 ghz with hyperthreading, so i suppose Prescott core.

I'm not sure my MB support it. I think yes, but i'm not sure. Does anyone know if that chipset support it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to this: http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleid=853&page=4

Is that your motherboard? Based on what I have read, the it is very questionable and varies by motherboard. Some with that chipset, for example, do support Prescott while some don't.

Check out AOpen's website for BIOS updates and see if there is anything there.

Those P4 processors are so cheap right now, you might even try just getting a used one and trying that out first.